# Unable to allocate free space to Ubuntu partition

Tags: 18.04, disk-usage, memory-usage, unallocated

So I'm kinda new to the Linux OS and I'm using Ubuntu, as it's said by many to be the best option for beginners. As I started using it more and more I stopped using it in a virtual-box and got my laptop to dual-boot with Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

As I wanted to install more and more programs to Ubuntu like Android Studio, I started getting errors caused by the lack of space on the /home partition.

Installing to other places on the Ubuntu disk didn't seem to help and as so I went on to unallocate 10Gb of space from my Win10 partition. The problem now is I can't allocate it to my /home partition. As you can see i have unallocated space just after my Windows10 partition and don't know what to do to get it to my /home partition.

Here is my gparted since i can't post img files https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXJlP.png

Comment: You cannot make any changes to a *mounted* partition - that's what the key icon indicates. Boot from a LiveUSB so none of your partitions are mounted, and then you can make changes.

Comment: I think it's because of the space between the partitions on the drive, can you move sda5, up into the unallocated space, then sda6, then expand sda 7?

Comment: Unless you have a lot of junk on your windows partition you can delete, I would suggest looking into buying an external hard drive or SSD.  With only 10GBs extra you would find yourself back looking for more space soon.  If you adjust Windows partition, should use Windows tools for safety.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: You really need a bigger disk... or remove some stuff from sda4, and use Windows `Disk Manager` to resize sda4... then move/resize the ext4/swap partitions with `gparted`...

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** sda5 partition all the way left
- **move** sda6 partition all the way left
- **move** sda7 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of sda7 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: How do I boot to a Ubuntu live usb

Comment: @PakitoGama Booting to a USB is a function of your BIOS. When you turn on the computer, it may tell you on the splash screen what special keys do... like F2 to enter the BIOS, or F12 to bring up a boot menu, where you can select USB boot. Make sure you have good backups BEFORE starting my procedure.

Comment: I still have the USB pendrive which I used to install the Ubuntu, is that ir? Should I boot into that? And if so, in what option?

Comment: @PakitoGama Yes, that's it. Boot it the same way that you did when you installed Ubuntu. When booting the USB, select the "Try Ubuntu" option.